# Voiceover accessibility of UITableView subviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uidatepicker, uiaccessibility

I currently have a `UITableViewController` and I'm adding a `UIDatePicker` as a subview as follows:

```
self.datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, 200, 200)];
self.datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeTime;
[self.tableview addSubview:self.datePicker];
```

which is ran in `viewDidLoad`.

The issue is that the `UIDatePicker` doesn't show up as an accessible element, and does not read out the current date and time with VoiceOver turned on. 
I have tried disabling `accessibilityElementsHidden` setting of the tableview, but that also disables the subview's accessibility. Effectively, if I can disable the accessibility of the UITableView when the UIDatePicker is selected, then it would work.

Note: The UITableViewCells do not overlap the UIDatePicker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UITableView` isn't designed to have subviews added directly to it. It implements the [`UIAccessibilityContainer` informal protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAccessibilityContainer_Protocol/) and provides accessibility elements to VoiceOver users, coordinating with the table view's delegate.

To resolve this, instead of adding subviews directly to the table view, add your picker view to a cell's `contentView`, a table section header/footer, or a table header/footer.

For more, see [Enhance the Accessibility of Table Views](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iPhoneAccessibility/Making_Application_Accessible/Making_Application_Accessible.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008785-CH102-SW3).

Comment: Also: [Enhancing the Accessibility of Table View Cells](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW5)